# Expandable case insensitive switch case for string comparison

Tags: expl3, strings, comparison, pdfstrcmp

I have spent the last few hours trying to come up with a good solution for my problem, but alas all solutions falls short. I want to create a switchcase for a function (In reality I need many different kinds, not just one for language, but I added it as an concrete example.)

My ideal switch case function has the following functionality

- It accepts commands as inputs (fully expandable)
- It is case insensitive

My code below is a switch case, but it fails both of the above requirements. 
Any help figuring out a proper way to do this is more than welcome.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[norsk,nynorsk,british,samin]{babel}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

% This allows the user to switch languages using a myriad of synonyms
% The four provided languages are: English, Norsk, Nynorsk and Samin
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\selectLang}[1]{%
  \stringcases%
  {#1}%
  {%
    % English synonyms
    {english}{\selectlanguage{british}}%
    %
    % Norsk (Bokmål) synonyms
    {norsk}{\selectlanguage{norsk}}%
    %
    % Nynorsk synonyms
    {nynorsk}{\selectlanguage{nynorsk}}%
    %
    % Samin synonyms
    {samisk}{\selectlanguage{samin}}%
    {samin}{\selectlanguage{samin}}%
  }%
  {}%
}

% Helper functions to create the switch case above
\newcommand{\stringcases}[3]{%
  \romannumeral
  \str@case{#1}#2{#1}{#3}\q@stop
}
\newcommand{\str@case}[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\str@case@end{#3}}
  {\str@case{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\str@case@end}{}
\long\def\str@case@end#1#2\q@stop{\z@#1}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\temptwo}{nynorsk}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\temp}{\temptwo}

\languagename

\selectLang{english}

\languagename % Displays english as it should

\selectLang{Norsk}

\languagename % This should display norsk

\selectLang{\temp}

\languagename % This should display nynorsk

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you don't want the command to _be expandable_ (since `\selectlanguage` is not). I think you want it to expand it's argument, right? In that case, simply remove the two `\unexpanded` in the definition of `\str@case`.

Comment: Yeah, the command is not supposed to be expandable. Only to expand the arguments =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the kind help of `expl3`, this is expandable (if the code of the cases is, so with the normal definition of `\selectlanguage` it isn't).

**EDIT:** as pointed out by [@JosephWright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508268/expandable-case-insensitive-switch-case-for-string-comparison/508274?noredirect=1#comment1326049_508274), `\str_foldcase:e` is to be used for this kind of task. As a general rule of thumb: For processing use `\str_foldcase:n`, for text which should be printed out use `\str_lowercase:n`.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \selectLang { m }
  {
    \str_case_e:nn { \str_foldcase:e { #1 } }
      {
        { english } { \selectlanguage{british} }
        { norsk }   { \selectlanguage{norsk} }
        { nynorsk } { \selectlanguage{nynorsk} }
        { samisk }  { \selectlanguage{samisk} }
        { samin }   { \selectlanguage{samin} }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_foldcase:n { e }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand\selectlanguage{} % just to show that it works

\begin{document}
Chosen language: \selectLang{EnGlIsH}

\def\foo{NOrsK}
Chosen language: \selectLang{\foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps `\NewDocumentCommand` or at least `\cs_new_protected:Npn`, since `\selectlanguage` doesn't expand.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes, that would be correct with the normal definition of `\selectlanguage` (not with the redefinition). I'll change it :)

Comment: Explainer for beginners: `\str_foldcase:e` doesn't exist by default and needs creating with the `\cs_generate_variant` statement. This `generate_variant` must be **executed before** the `\selectLang` command is used otherwise you get an error. This is independent of the order in which the code is written. As a beginner myself I found it helpful to put the `generate_variant` physically before the `\NewDocumentCommand` that makes use of it.

Comment: Another two traps for beginners I fell into. First the `\selectlanguage` command might not work well if **executed** (as opposed to just written as it is in the answer) from the preamble, that is executed before `\begin{document}` Second I had problems by executing commands in the preamble that tried to typeset text. I was so enchanted and frustrated by `expl3` that I forgot you can't put text into a document that hasn't started yet. These two things seem obvious now but they absolutely weren't at the time.