# How can I make a case-insensitive compare with expl3?

Tags: expl3

I am in the process of writing a macro which takes a 4 digit hex value and does something based on the input. I want to achieve, that a user can use uppercase or lowercase characters for the hex code. What already works is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\actionForHEX}{m}{%
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
    {
        {E085} {This is E085}
        {E086} {This is E086}
    }
    {Unknown}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Works: \actionForHEX{E085}

Does not work: \actionForHEX{e085}
\end{document}
```

So in principal I can define actions, but I do not understand the use of `\str_flipcase:n` to allow the case to work for lowercase as well.

Based on [Expandable case insensitive switch case for string comparison](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508268/expandable-case-insensitive-switch-case-for-string-comparison) I tried something, but this had no success at all:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\actionForHEX}{m}{%
    \str_case_e:nn { \str_foldcase:e { #1 } }
    {
        {E085} {This is E085}
        {E086} {This is E086}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

Ok, based on your input I tried my luck again, but it seems I still don't understand something. This is my new approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\actionForHEX}{m}{%
    \str_case:nnF { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
    {
        {e085} {This~is~E085}
        {e086} {This~is~E086}
    }
    {Cannot~find~it}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Does not work: \actionForHEX{E085}

Does not work: \actionForHEX{e085}
\end{document}
```

This results in `Canot find it` for both calls of `\actionForHEX`

Comment: Shouldn't your test cases be `e085` and `e086`, resp.?

Comment: What cgnieder says: With `\str_foldcase` you case-fold the input, now your comparison text must be case-folded as well. Case folding is largely based on lowercase, so you need to compare against `e085` and `e086`. If you want to use `\str_foldcase:e` you'll need `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_foldcase:n { e }` as in the linked answer. You probably also want to write `This~is~E085` to get spaces between the words.

Comment: @moewe Looks like an answer to me

Comment: I actually don't need to expand macros here, I will only use straight inputs. I attached a new approach, but this makes it worse, not better, I don't get, why. Do I need `\str_case_e:nnF {\str_foldcase:n{#1}}` ? This results in an undefined control sequence for `\actionForHEX`

Comment: @TobiBS Yes, but you _do_ need to expand `\str_foldcase:n`, otherwise the comparison will be between the _literal_ strings `\str_foldcase:n{e085}` and `e085`. Try `\exp_args:Ne \str_case:nnF { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }`

Comment: It seems I found the issue. `\exp_args` was introduced in May 2018 and `\str_foldcase` November 2019. Hence they are both not available with TeX Live 2017 and a MikTeX version from early 2018 that I used.
Thanks for explaining the misconception about expansion and sorry for not seeing earlier, that this is a problem of the used version.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Just curious: Is there a (meaningful) difference between `\exp_args:Ne \str_case:nnF { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }` and `\str_case:enF { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }` (after `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { en }`)?

Comment: @moewe None, except that the former is the lazy, less recommended version :-) (though for the branching conditional you might need `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn` instead). Also you can omit trailing `n` and `N` when generating variants

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comments by [cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder) you need to compare against `e085` and `e086`, respectively, since you are comparing against the case-folded input (`\str_foldcase:n { #1 }`). Broadly speaking, case folding is based on lowercase, so the input `E085` gets folded into `e085` and that's what you need to compare against.

Because we apply a macro to the input, we can't directly compare the strings with as normal `n` arguments. We need to make sure that `\str_foldcase:n { #1 }` is expanded first.

This can be done as in [Skillmon likes topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon-likes-topanswers-xyz)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508274/35864) to [Expandable case insensitive switch case for string comparison](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/508268/35864) with `\str_case_e:nn`

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\actionForHEX}{m}{%
  \str_case_e:nn { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
    {
        {e085} {This~is~E085}
        {e086} {This~is~E086}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

That command will fully expand all involved strings with the new `e`-type expansion. (So `\str_foldcase:n { #1 }` is expanded, which is nice. And `e085` and `e086` are expanded as well, which is a bit pointless).

We can avoid the the expansion of `e085` and `e086` by generating the `en`-variant of `\str_case:nn`, which only expands `\str_foldcase:n { #1 }`

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { e }

\NewDocumentCommand{\actionForHEX}{m}{%
  \str_case:en { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
    {
        {e085} {This~is~E085}
        {e086} {This~is~E086}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If you are using an old system where `e`-type expansion is not available, you can try `x`-type expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { x }

\NewDocumentCommand{\actionForHEX}{m}{%
  \str_case:xn { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
    {
        {e085} {This~is~E085}
        {e086} {This~is~E086}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\actionForHEX{E085}

\actionForHEX{e085}

\actionForHEX{E086}

\actionForHEX{e086}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is E085//This is E085//This is E086//This is E086]

On older systems `\str_fold_case:n` (introduced before November 2016, see [`l3news10`](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex3-news/l3news10.pdf)) may work instead of `\str_foldcase:n` (which replaced `\str_fold_case` on 2019-11-26).

---

If you want to include an `F` non-matching branch at the end, it is better to generate the variants with `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn` (thanks to [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) for explaining that in the comments). For `e`-type expansion that would look as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_case:nn { e } { F }

\NewDocumentCommand{\actionForHEX}{m}{%
  \str_case:enF { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
    {
        {e085} {This~is~E085}
        {e086} {This~is~E086}
    }
    {Not~matched}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\actionForHEX{E085}

\actionForHEX{e085}

\actionForHEX{E086}

\actionForHEX{e086}

\actionForHEX{E087}
\end{document}
```

It would be analogous for `x`-type expansion (and possibly `\str_fold_case:n` on older systems).

Comment: Thanks @moewe, I am still a total newbie to expl3 and this helped me a lot to understand. I was now also able to expand your solution to a variant with a false tree:

`\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF {xn}

\NewDocumentCommand{\actionForHEX}{m}{%
 \str_case:xnF {\str_fold_case:n{#1}}
 {
  {e085} {This~is~E085}
  {e086} {This~is~E086}
 }
 {Alternative}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: @TobiBS The code you show should work (it does for me) however for branching conditionals you should use `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_case:nn { x } { F }` instead. The first argument is the function without the conditionals in the signature, the second is the list of variants (same as for `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`), and the third is the list of branching conditionals. Note also that trailing `n` and `N` are redundant when generating variants and can be omitted.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik So `prg_generate_conditional_variant` is benefitial, because it does not expand the false clause, is that the point? Does this change the line `\str_case:xnF {\str_fold_case:n{#1}}`?

Comment: @TobiBS I'm not sure I understand your question... Using `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` in a conditional function like `\str_case:nnF` works because of how it's implemented (and that's probably not going to change), but it's conceptually incorrect. Since `\str_case:nnF` is a conditional, you should use `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn` (which also makes it easier if you want to define also the `T`, `TF`, and `p` forms).  But as I said, the code you posted in your first comment should work as well...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik understood and I got your point. I tried to find `\prg_generate_conditional_variant` in my old documentation and couldn't, now after referring to the latest version, I see the reason: `New: 2017-12-12`
So it seems I have to stick with my solution until we upgrade to a later version of MikTeX and TeXlive.

Comment: @TobiBS Yeah, `expl3` has advanced quite a lot in the past few years, so 2017 is rather outdated.